# Error while setup gitlab and jenkins in windows 10

Tags: git, jenkins, windows-10, gitlab

Installing and setup jenkins in local and trying to connect remote repository and add a job in jenkins. Lot of solutions are out there but haven't helped any.

but am facing this error while adding the remote repository in Source code management-->git-->

```
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: 
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\ ls-remote -h 
git@gitlab:user/project.git HEAD
```

I have installed jenkins in my local machine windows 10
Remote repository is gitlab, have created a repository
Could not add a new Item in jenkins due to this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the `Git Executable file path`. Please Goto `Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> Git -> Path to Git executable` and refer the complete path to `git` file. If your git already in the system path, then you can use just `git` in that field. Hope this helps.

Comment: i have tried that..like C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe..This you mean right?both haven't worked

Comment: try using just 'git' itself. Can you able to access 'git' from CMD?

Comment: yes i can use git in cmd, but git.exe in exist in the path i specified...

Comment: just use 'git' not 'git.exe' in the path. If that does not work, use this 'C://Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/bin/git.exe'.

Comment: Thanks, let me check

Comment: Hi, do i need to change the environment variable in windows with same? 'git'

Comment: i got this error when added git ,  Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@gitlab:user/project.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists

Comment: that error because of you did not add any access token to git. Please goto `Settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal Access Token` and see the process how to generate one.

Comment: Can i ask one question? is it possible to run jenkins in local windows machine and do the listentnig, pulling, testing code and all?I wonder i should isntall in some online server or somewhere ..

Comment: you can simply install it in your local machine and test all these thing out. Just add plugins after successful installation so that your local copy works like your working copy.

Comment: Ok,Thanks.I have added key already in gitlab... for some other project so my machine is known to gitlab now right?I believe i donot need to generate and add key in gitlab again..

Comment: Not working yet.. 
Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe ls-remote -h git@gitlab:user/cdci-pipeline.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists

Comment: Did you set up all credentials required for jenkins to communicate to git ???
`Settings -> GitHub Pull Request Builder -> GitHub Auth`

Comment: No,not added what should be added ? It is not github am using gitlab

Comment: Heyy. U have to atleast authenticate to the github right. [Link to setup](https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/02/27/configuring-ssh-authentication-between-github-and-jenkins/)

Comment: First time implemeneting so..I have added gitlab credentials to jenkins is that right?

Comment: its okay. no problem. if you added it, please click on test credentials and wait for success. If thats not happen, its wrong. please check again okay.

Comment: ok, thanks i think some more settings are there to add in order to sync my windows local machine ,jenkins and gitlab...

Comment: Could you please send any good tutorial for configuring jenkins and gitlab in windows local machine..Thanks

Comment: Hope this tutorial Helps . [Github Jenkins Authentication Setup](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb)